# Java-Maven Dependency: Project A depends on project B. Does it mean that Project A uses Project B's jar/war file to build or run its files?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project A that depends on many other projects namely B, C, D, E and F all of which are Maven projects.  I notice that I have to do Maven Update and Maven Install for B, C, D, E and F for running and building A correctly. I wanted to know what happens during this process and is A using the jar files of other projects or compiles others too. Could you please help out? I am using Eclipse and its Maven plugin.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know what happens during this process and is A using the jar files of other projects or compiles others too

If A needs inputs from other projects during the runtime it obviously needs those jar files. But it doesn't compiles other jar files when you execute A.

> I notice that I have to do Maven Update and Maven Install for B, C,
>   D, E and F for running and building A correctly

You do this because the changes made in B,C,D,E needs to be known to A , when it is expecting the input from them. else new changes will not work

Answer (score 1):

When compiling project A maven will first try to look-up the project dependencies B, C, D, E.
He will look at the local repository (usually a hidden directory .m2 under user’s home directory) or a remote repository.

In your case B, C, D, E  are your local projects and not third-party so executing maven install for B, C, D, E. will compile them and copy them to local repository.
When you do maven install on A they will not be compiled again.